# how to set value to a span tag in ruby

Tags: ruby, xpath

how can you set a value to the span tag instead?

e.g.

```
span :span_text, xpath: '//span[@class="spanClass"]'

def set span_text mystring
  span_text.text="#{mystring}"
end
```

with the above code, I am getting undefined method 'text=' for "":String (NoMethodError)

Comment: Are you using any framework? As far as I can tell you have some syntax errors in your code and also you are not telling us what the method/variable `span` is in your context.

Comment: I am using ruby/selenium/watir.

Comment: span  :personal_details_name, xpath: '//div[@class="your-details-inner"]/ul[@class="your-details__list"][1]/li/span[contains(data-bind, name)]'

def verify_personal_details first_name, last_name, mobile_number, email
  personal_details_name_element.text=first_name+" "+last_name
end


it gives me an error: undefined method `text=' for #<Watir::Span:0x42e3580> (NoMethodError)